# Query a JSON array in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have the following JSON object.

```
SET @j = '{"id": [1, 2, 4]}'
```

I'm trying to query the JSON object to find if the id contain 2 in it.

```
select JSON_CONTAINS(@j,'one','%2')
```

I don't think the above `JSON_CONTAINS` are correct but I'm not sure what would I do to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry @rev_dihazum that did not work but this did.

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@j, '1', '$.id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(@j, "$.id"), 'one', '2');
```